# SQL query Distinct / Group By not working

Tags: select, duplicates, left-join

I'm not a very good select-statement artisan and was hoping someone could help. I have two manufacturing parts tables:

The STOCK Table has the standing inventory in it. It has all the part numbers in it which exist over multiple rows because the parts are scattered in multiple locations. This is correct.

The RECEIPT Table is a table someone built. It is simply the latest year a part was received in. Each row is only the Part Number and the Receipt Year. Part numbers are only distinctly listed once.

I'm trying to glue the Receipt Year column onto the original STOCK table to just report on the  year a part was received. I dont want to alter the original data in the STOCK table, just add the receipt year to each row based on a match on PART NUMBER.
 Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STOCK.Project, STOCK.[Part Id], STOCK.Warehouse, STOCK.Location, RECEIPTS.Year from STOCK LEFT JOIN RECEIPTS on STOCK.[Part Id] = RECEIPTS.ITEM_ID GROUP BY STOCK.Project, STOCK.[Part Id], STOCK.Warehouse, STOCK.Location, RECEIPTS.Year;
```

Unfortunately, my query keeps duplicating out the rows against each Year available in the RECEIPTS table, like this:

```
Proj        Part Id         Whse_ID Loc         Receipt_Year
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2004
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2005
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2006
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2007
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2009
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2011
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2012
A198.730    5962-9313101MPA 770 GFMSTK-116B2    2013
```

That 5962- part was received in 2004 only (one distinct row in RECEIPTS).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 0):

resolved with a primer query that pulls the max date records on the data first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry I resolved the problem myself with two subsequent queries. The first query pulls the data with the max date to eliminate the duplicate records then the second query completes the filters I needed